# What driver to choose on Dell XPS 13 9380?

Tags: drivers, dell, xps

I just got a Dell XPS 13 9380 and installed the [OEM Ubuntu 18.04.03](https://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER05544477M/1/) provided by Dell and I wonder what driver to use?

[image: neofetch]

[image: Software & Updates]

Comment: We need to know more about what exactly this device *is* to give you a better answer.  What does `ubuntu-drivers devices` when run on the Command Line say about the device it's referring to?  Also, this is a Dell OEM setup and NOT a typical 'default' Ubuntu installation, I would leave drivers/configurations alone if you're usinh the OEM ISO from Dell.

Comment: It is better not to change anything. This is a Dell specific OEM setup.

Comment: [Here's](https://i.imgur.com/XsO8RoD.png) the output of `ubuntu-drivers devices`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a matter of "choosing a driver".

Dell pre-installed some packages that are displayed there as a "drivers" for a "Device". That is not actually the case.

I suggest to leave it as is or consult Dell support.

Comment: I'll leave it as is, thank you